# How to print list returned by a function

Tags: scala

I wrote code which filters some values. I try to print results but I receive :Unit type and nothing is printed. How can I fix the code?

```
val originalList = List(5, -1, 0, 3, 2)

 def without(originalList: List [Int] ) : List[Int] = {
     val newList = originalList.filter(_ == 3)

      return newList
   }

val list=without(originalList)
for( a <- list ){
         println();
      }
```

Comment: If my answer is correct then please accept the answer by clicking on the right mark in he left of the answer thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is actually fine but you are missing what you need to print inside the for loop you are not giving the value in println which is a.

When you write `for(a <- list)` that means for a in list where a is the element of the list. And you need to print the element of the list which is a. So you do

`println(a)`

You can use foreach

```
without(originalList).foreach(println)
```

You can directly do `println(list)`

In your code

```
val list=without(originalList)
for( a <- list ){
         println(a)
      }
```

Actually in your code you don’t need return statement as the last line of a function in scala is considered as return value.

```
val originalList = List(5, -1, 0, 3, 2)

 def without(originalList: List [Int] ) : List[Int] = originalList.filter(_ == 3)

val list=without(originalList)
for( a <- list ){
         println(a)
      }
```